# Error making a post request to my api on Heroku

Tags: spring-boot, heroku

Upload an api made in Spring Boot to heroku, all the Gets methods are working correctly, but the Posts have a problem where only the first request I make works, after that it doesn't work anymore, only if I restart the application. What do I do?

Comment: Have you tested it locally with bootRun to make sure that this is a heroku issue? Is there anything meaningful in logs? Is it possible that the application crashes after the first POST request (i.e. are other methods responsive?)

Comment: I did all the tests locally, and everything was working correctly, all get and post methods. After I switched to heroku only the get works, the post only works once when the application starts